# How to make JavaFX stage transparent (Stage Only)

Tags: javafx, transparent

The example below works for the Text only but once I add a button to the stage, the transparent become inactive

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        Text text = new Text("!");
        text.setFont(new Font(40));
        VBox box = new VBox();
        Button btn = new Button("Test transparent");
        box.getChildren().addAll(text, btn);
        //if I removed the btn, transparent works as expected. 
        final Scene scene = new Scene(box,300, 250);
        scene.setFill(null);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

What I am looking for is to only make the stage transparent but show the text and button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Button` in that case is not an issue. By default `VBox` has gray background, so your `Stage` is transparent, but VBox isn't. You have to set transparent background by CSS file or inline or from code:

CSS:

```
.your-vbox {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

Inline:

```
box.setStyle("-fx-background-color: transparent;");
```

Code:

```
box.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.TRANSPARENT, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!